# How to Switch-Case many variables in C# (that checks if the values are null or empty) to replace if-else-if chain

Tags: c#, if-statement, stored-procedures, switch-statement, isnullorempty

How to Switch-Case many variables in C# (that checks if the values are null or empty) to replace the giant if-else-if chain (+20 else-ifs) . How can I have less and more efficient code replacing my code with Switch statements :

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_AddPublisher", con);
        cmd.CommandText = "usp_AddPublisher";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Account_Num))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNum", "");
        }
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNum", data.Account_Num);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.publisher))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher", "");
        }
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher", data.publisher);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.addr1))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr1", "");
        }
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr1", data.addr1);
```

**I tried** but it's too long :

```
  con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_AddPublisher", con);
        cmd.CommandText = "usp_AddPublisher";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
switch (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Account_Num))
        {
            case true:
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNum", "");
                break;
            case false:
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNum", data.Account_Num);
                break;

        }
  switch (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.publisher))
            {
                case true:
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher", "");
                    break;
                case false:
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher", data.publisher);
                    break;
            }
            switch (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.addr1))
            {
                case true:
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr1", "");
                    break;
                case false:
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr1", data.addr1);
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given all you're doing is using `""` as the value when a string is null or empty, you're just coalescing `null` to `""`. So just do that:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNum", data.Account_Num ?? "")
```

If you've not come across the null coalescing operator `??` before, you can read about it [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something as this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addr1", string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.addr1) ? "" : data.addr1);
```

or even better you could create an extension method that would return the value of the string, when the string is not null or empty, otherwise it would return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use the [conditional operator `?:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNum", String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Account_Num) ? "" : data.Account_Num);
```

or - like Charles Mager already stated (and is more readable) - the [null-coalescing operator `??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) operator like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNum", data.Account_Num ?? "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use local functions (C#7 / VS 2017):

```
void TheOuterFunction() 
{
    // your cmd is set up here
    var cmd = ...;
    ...;

    AddParameter("@AccountNum", data.Account_Num);
    AddParameter("@publisher", data.publisher);
    ...;

    void AddParameter(string name, string value)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, "");
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This keeps the logic involved clearly visible and reduces the "overhead" for each parameter that needs the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate function:

```
public void SomeFunction()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_AddPublisher", con);
    cmd.CommandText = "usp_AddPublisher";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SwitchFunction(data.Account_Num, "@AccountNum", cmd);
    SwitchFunction(data.publisher, "@publisher", cmd);
    SwitchFunction(data.addr1, "@addr1", cmd);
}

public void SwitchFunction(string testVar, string withVal, SqlCommand cmd)
{
    switch (String.IsNullOrEmpty(testVar))
    {
        case true:
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(withVal, string.Empty);
            break;
        case false:
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(withVal, testVar);
            break;
    }
}
```